# Selecting Nth child from join table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I've got a TSQL query, a basic one-to-many type association which looks something like this:

```
SELECT  Palette.Palette_ID
        Colour.Name
FROM    Palette
INNER JOIN Colour
    ON Palette.Palette_ID = Colour.Palette_ID
```

This results in a fairly standard dataset like so, whereby each palette can have an unknown number of colours related to it, maybe none, maybe 20, maybe more:

```
Palette ID | Colour Name
========================
1          | Red
1          | Blue
2          | Yellow
2          | Red
2          | Orange
3          | Pink
4          | Red
4          | Yellow
```

I'm looking to write a query which gives me a somewhat pivoted dataset, with 3 columns which give me the first 3 colour accocicated with a Pallette, something like this:

```
Palette ID | First Colour | Second Colour | Third Colour
========================================================
1          | Red          | Blue          | NULL
2          | Yellow       | Red           | Orange
3          | Pink         | NULL          | NULL
4          | Red          | Yellow        | NULL
```

I understand how I might be able to approach this using a GROUP BY and SELECT MIN() MAX() in order to get the first and last colour choices for a given palette, however I'm not sure how to go about selecting the nth joined row like this.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated. I've spent too much time using ORMs and I'm completely out of touch with SQL.

Comment: Will it be always three colurs

Comment: Lookup dynamic cross tab or dynamic pivot. It has been answered around here and lots of other places around the internet hundreds of times.

Answer (score 0):

Use a ROW_NUMBER() function:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms186734.aspx

In your query, something like

```
SELECT  Palette.Palette_ID,
        Colour.Name,
ROW_NUMBER ( ) 
        OVER ( PARTITION BY Palette.Palette_ID ORDER BY Colour.Name ) row_num
FROM    Palette
INNER JOIN Colour
    ON Palette.Palette_ID = Colour.Palette_ID
```

This should add a sequential number to each of the rows for each palette, re-initialising when the palette changes. In your case you don't appear to be ordering by colour name, so you may need to tweak the order by clause.

Answer (score 0):

How about the following - uses the ROW_NUMBER function.

```
WITH c AS (
  SELECT 
    Palette_ID, 
    Name, 
    ROW_NUMBER OVER (PARTITION BY Palette_ID ORDER BY Name) AS rn
  FROM Colour
)
SELECT 
  p.Palette_ID, 
  c1.Name AS [First Colour],
  c2.Name AS [Second Colour],
  c3.Name AS [Third Colour]
FROM Palette AS p
  LEFT JOIN c AS c1 ON p.Palette_ID = c1.Palette_ID AND c1.rn = 1
  LEFT JOIN c AS c2 ON p.Palette_ID = c2.Palette_ID AND c2.rn = 2
  LEFT JOIN c AS c3 ON p.Palette_ID = c3.Palette_ID AND c3.rn = 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Pivot` to **transpose** the rows to columns.

```
CREATE TABLE #test1
  (Palette_ID  INT,Colour_Name VARCHAR(50))

INSERT #test1
VALUES (1,'Red'),(1,'Blue'),(2,'Yellow'),
       (2,'Red'),(2,'Orange'),(3,'Pink'),
       (4,'Red'),(4,'Yellow')

SELECT Palette_ID,
       [1 color] First_Color,
       [2 color] Second_Color,
       [3 color] Third_Color
FROM   (SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), Row_number() OVER (partition BY Palette_ID ORDER BY Colour_Name))
               + ' Color' AS dd,
               *
        FROM   #test1) a
       PIVOT (Max(Colour_Name)
             FOR dd IN([1 color],
                       [2 color],
                       [3 color]))piv
```